# Is it possible for someone to awaken the Mangekyou Sharingan before they even awaken the Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

I was just wondering if it was possible for an Uchiha to awaken the Mangekyou Sharingan before even awakening the Sharingan.

According to [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan):

> It (Mangekyou Sharingan) is initially awakened by the trauma suffered from witnessing the death of someone close to the user.

I think it should be common sense by now, but if you didn't know then to awaken the MS the user has to witness something so traumatic, like seeing someone close to the said user die.

According to [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sharingan):

> When a wielder of this kekkei genkai experiences a powerful emotional condition with regards to a person precious to them, their brain releases a special form of chakra that affects the optic nerves, transforming the eyes into Sharingan.

To awaken the Sharingan, an Uchiha has to have an extreme(powerful) emotion condition which causes their brain to release a special type of chakra, which will then cause their eyes to transform into Sharingan.

I have put the way the Uchiha awaken the Sharingan and the MS, but could it be possible to combine both of the said ways into one? What I mean is if an Uchiha, who hasn't awakened the Sharingan yet, witnessed something so traumatic they just awaked the MS. Could that even be possible? Or would it just awaken the Sharingan and then the MS almost instantly at the same time?

Comment: You answered your own question

Comment: @Aogiri, in my question I put a theory I came up with, but I'm asking if it's possible... Are you saying my theory is right?

Comment: Since MS is a type of Sharingan, it simply follows that a person may awaken both, but not MS alone. MS can be activated seperately, causes blindness by overuse, so usually someone who already has experience with Sharingan may realise that he can unlock it to the next level. It is pretty clear that you can't have MS without Sharingan

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I believe the death of the whole clan (especially the death of someone's parents by one of their own siblings - Itachi) is more traumatic than anything and when Sasuke with all those emotions could never achieve it in such a long time, I am sure it can not be achieved without achieving the basic Sharingan levels.

And most importantly, you can not simply do a maths questions without knowing the basics... So basics, i.e Sharingan must be present before the awakening of Mangekyou :)

That is simply what I believe, what is in the minds of Masashi, we don't know :P

Comment: The only clue we have is that Sasuke didn't even awaken a regular Sharingan due to the massacre, though we know he could use grand fireball at the time. So either it was incorrect, done incorrectly, or possibly sasuke was not strong enough to even awaken the regular Sharingan at the time. As well, I bet if he did awaken his Mangekyou at that time, he probably would have awoken the Sharingan a few seconds earlier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you could achieve it: is someone transplanted their eye to you while in Mangekyo mode, but I highly doubt it would not have the original Sharingan.

So, my answer is **no**, because the Mangekyo Sharingan evolves from the Sharingan.

Let me give an example... Let's say, in chemistry, Mixture A mixed with Mixture B = Mixture C, and that's the only way to get Mixture C. In this scenario, Mixture A is the Sharingan, Mixture B is killing all you hold dear (I think the only method of obtaining the Mangekyo Sharingan from the Sharingan without someone giving it to you, like Shisui giving Itachi the Magekyo Sharingan before he died), and Mixture C is the Mangekyo Sharingan.

By the way, if you are a child and don't understand my example, I don't blame you... Chemistry is kind of a nuisance. :)

Comment: Yeah, I think putting it in that way makes more sense. +1